# matlab sqlite database performance

Tags: matlab, performance, sqlite

I use JDBC driver to connect a sqlite database from matlab. I define a function to open the database which looks like this:

```
   function db_conn = openDBConnection(sqldb_obj, configOptions)

        try
            sqldb_obj.dbConn = database(sqldb_obj.dbName, sqldb_obj.userName, sqldb_obj.password, sqldb_obj.JDBC_SQLITE_DRIVER, sqldb_obj.DB_URL);
            db_conn = sqldb_obj.dbConn;                
        catch runtimeError

        end            
    end
```

Each time this openConnection( ) is called before the execute( ).

```
function result = execute(sqldb_obj, sql_statement, varargin)

            sqldb_obj.openDBConnection();

            curs = exec(sqldb_obj.dbConn, sql_statement);

            if curs.ResultSet ~= 0                  
                curs = fetch(curs);
                if rows(curs) == 0
                    result = [];
                else
                    result = curs.Data;
                end
            else
                % for the insert query 
                result = curs.Data;
            end

            % Disconnect the database connection
            close(curs);            
 end
```

The performance is very slow when I insert a table in a for loop. From the profiler, I get that it takes 754.595 secs for the function `com.mathwork.toolbox.database.closeTheDatabaseConnection`.

How to improve the performance and where is the problem is?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you reopening the database for every query?

Comment: I do not find a good way to only open the database once. Can you refer some good examples to me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I find that inside a for loop, there is another function called getTable(). In this getTable(), it opens and closes the db. So it takes a lot of time.